# Reset validation for Paper Input?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I have a paper-input element like this:

```
<paper-input id="inputForValidation" required label="this input is manually validated" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" error-message="letters only!"></paper-input>
<button onclick="validate()">Validate!</button>
```

When I validate the input and the validation fails it looks like this:

[image]

Without changing the input I want to programmatically reset the validation state such that it looks like before:

[image]

**How can I reset the validation state to get the unvalidated view without changing the input?**

Comment: This is probably not the best way but you could set the `invalid` property of the `paper-input` to false as there doesn't appear to be any method in the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input) that would allow you to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "without changing the input"? If the input pattern is OK, you could remove the error message by calling again 'inputForValidation.validate()', no?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the invalid attribute of the paper-input element to false, e.g.

```
this.$.inputForValidation.invalid = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you want the empty value is valid so you just have to remove the require attribute...

In more complicated case I think you want to do something like this :

```
Polymer({
  is: "my-element",
  validate: function(){
   if(this.$.inputForValidation.value == ""){
   //When the input is empty we want
    this.$.inputForValidation.removeAttribute("required");
    this.$.inputForValidation.validate();
    this.$.inputForValidation.setAttribute("required", true);
   }
  }
});
```